# dropdown is not working - bootstrap - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

Part of my navbar code is below, which is supposed to activate when the image is clicked but it is not working.
I have bootstrap working on my website as if i type `class="text-primary"` the text will turn blue.
so im not sure what is wrong, or is it super obvious? thanks

```html
     
        <div class="dropdown">
          <%= image_tag "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507146426996-ef05306b995a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80", class: "avatar dropdown-toggle", id: "navbar-wagon-menu", "data-toggle" => "dropdown" %>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right navbar-wagon-dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <%= link_to "#" do %>
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <%= t(".profile", default: "Profile") %>
              <% end %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "#" do %>
                <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>  <%= t(".settings", default: "Settings") %>
              <% end %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do %>
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>  <%= t(".sign_out", default: "Log out") %>
              <% end %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: How did you add bootstrap to the project? With a gem? If yes, check if you required it in application.js according to gem docs

Comment: yeah i added it with a gem. It has been required in application.js and it is not working still. @Vasilisa

Comment: Do you use turbolinks? If you refresh the page, the dropdown starts to work or still not working? Please, add application.js to the question?